# Default arguments C++ for all parameters that exists

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, default-arguments

I am looking for an example of code that shows that there are some parameters types which can't be assigned with default arguments. 
I mean, I want to disprove the statement "You can define a default argument for every parameter in a function", or, is it true actually?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX for `struct foo {};` and `void test(foo a)`, the `a` cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: @t.niese yeah I  realized, that I didn't understand what default arguments meant :D

Comment: You could create a class that cannot be constructed, but that would not make to much sense.

Answer (score 2):

That might be too much of a corner case, but you cannot provide default value for parameter packs:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... = 5) {};  //fails to compile
```

Answer (score 1):

Another corner case is for non-constructible class, (but function is not callable in regular way neither):

```
struct S{
    S() = delete;
    S(const S&) = delete;
};

void foo(S = {}); // Wrong
```

We might try to extend that, with visibility, using pass-key idiom, which will indeed forbid declaration with default parameter to some places, but we can (re-)declare function (with default parameter) in function scope, where key creation would be available...